# RSpec mocks not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-mocks

I'm trying to create a test on a controller using an rspec mock of a model, and it seems to only work when I say

```
Type.any_instance.should_recieve(...)
```

instead of

```
instancename.should_receive(...)
```

My code looks like this. (normally I use FactoryGirl, but I am not in this example to make sure that it's not the problem)

```
it "calls blah on foo" do
  foo = Foo.new
  foo.save
  foo.should_receive(:blah) #this fails because it's called 0 times
  #Foo.any_instance.should_receive(:blah) #this would succeed
  post :create, {:foo => foo}
end
```

and in my Controller

```
def create
  foo = Foo.find_by_id(params[:foo])
  foo.blah
  #other stuff thats not related
end
```

I know I could mock Foo.find_by_id and have it return foo, but I feel like I shouldn't need to do that because it should be returned anyway, and that means the test would break if I stopped using find_by_id, which is really not an important detail.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I feel like my test would be better if I didn't have to say any_instance everywhere and didn't have to mock find_by_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because it is not the same `foo` *object* that is being called with `blah` in your actual code.

In your spec code, you create an instance and save it:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.save
```

This saves a record to the db, which `foo` points to. You then put an expectation on the object:

```
foo.should_receive(:blah)
```

This expectation will only work if the spec and app code point to the same *object*. You can achieve this, as you note, by for example stubbing `find_by_id` to return it. Alternatively, you can also set an expectation on any instance, which you also note.

However, the expectation will not work as-is. In your actual code, you create a *different* object `foo`:

```
foo = Foo.find_by_id(params[:foo])
foo.blah
```

If `params[:foo]` is the id for the record, then both `foo` in your spec code and `foo` in your app code point to the same record, but that does not mean that they are the same object (they are not).

Also, if I understand correctly, I believe that this:

```
post :create, {:foo => foo}
```

should be:

```
post :create, {:foo => foo.id}
```

So, in a nutshell, if what you want is a message expectation, you'll need to either stub `find` or apply the expectation on any instance. (Note that you should be able to stub `find` rather than `find_by_id`, since the dynamic finders call through to `find` anyway and that should make your test more robust.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of what I was thinking, I just hoped there was a way without calling find_by_id. Calling find seems like a better solution, so I'll do that.

Comment: Just a heads up. I don't think the part about find_by_id calling find works. I tried it and it failed until i switched find to find_by_id.

Comment: Sorry I have to review that, I thought I'd done that somewhere but I might be wrong. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Actually, `find_by_id` is the same as `find` in this context so you might as well use `find` for both, and avoid the stubbing dynamic finder issue altogether.

Comment: What do you mean they're the same? I prefer find_by_id because it doesn't throw exceptions when it can't find the object.

Comment: Sorry I just meant that `find` defaults to searching by `id`.

Comment: ah yea. im just gonna mock find_by_id since it doesn't throw exceptions. if the code ever changes and stops using find_by_id, that mock will complain and will be easy to change.